# Hypernym for "clock" and "watch"

Tags: single-word-requests, time, hypernyms

Yesterday I said: "I can't read analog clocks", but my interlocutor corrected me saying that what I was pointing at was a watch and not a clock.

Now, I am aware of the difference between the two, but how can I say I can read neither analog clocks nor analog watches? Is there a hypernym for both of them?

Comment: A watch is also clock. A clock is any time-keeping device, including a virtual one like the system clock that runs in the computer. The hypernym is **clock.**

Comment: *I can't read analog devices.* In idiomatic English, everyone knows that a clock is not a watch, *and* vice versa. But there are only those two choices. A *hypernym* is unnecessary and potentially confusing; the best thing to do is to remember that a *watch* goes on one's *wrist* (or *pocket*)  and a *clock* does not.

Comment: Just learn it, damnit.

Comment: Your interlocutor is being unnecessarily pedantic.

Comment: @CarSmack Being as pedantic as the person mentioned in the question, "analog devices" would also include books and exclude e-readers

Comment: You could respond that being unable to read analog clocks (even if the term does exclude wristwatches, which IMHO it does not) implies that you also cannot read analog watches.

Comment: @Izkata A watch is an analog device in the sense that the angle of the hands is analogous to the time - as the time increases so does the angle. What is analogous to what with a book?

Comment: @bdsl [Analog (adjective)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/analog): "of or relating to a device or process in which data is represented by physical quantities that change continuously" - in this case, position through the story. It's just used in this manner most often with timepieces.

Comment: A watch *is* a clock.

Comment: Technically, since a traditional mechanical watch or clock uses an escapement that lets the gears advance in discrete steps, the word "analog" does not apply to it in the same sense it applies to a computer. But the online Merriam-Webster specifically (and correctly) notes that the word "analog", applied to a watch or clock, means it has hour and minute hands.

Comment: @Izkata So the difference between a conventional book and an e-reader is that with an e-reader I can only read one word at at time, but with a book I can take a break after reading 120.537 words?

Comment: @DavidK The difference is that the physical book has a physical component that tracks progress:  The number of pages turned.  E-readers do not, just a number on the screen.  And don't forget, often analog clocks are made to tick seconds instead of having smooth motion.  You can't measure partial seconds on my watch, for example, so it would _technically_ not be analog by your description, except that _is_ how it's described.

Comment: @Izkata Again, "analog watch" is defined in dictionaries. It is a well-known term. I merely question whether it's an application of a general definition of "analog." The fact that the page number of a book is tied to a physical object makes it _less_ "analog": you advance in larger discrete units. I've heard these called "paper" books, "physical" books, or "hardcopy," but never "analog."

Comment: @Izkata: "analog devices" would certainly include sliderules and mechanical scales.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The word is [*timepiece*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/timepiece):

> Any device that measures or registers time; a clock or watch, especially one lacking a chime or other striking mechanism.

But it's not really used much, and as the usage notes on that page explain, your interlocutor can just as easily object that clocks are not strictly timepieces. So you can keep on looking to say something like "I can't read analog timekeeping devices" or what have you, *or* you might as well save yourself the trouble and simply say, "I can't read analog".

Comment: Oh and of course there's the side note that a real picky interlocutor might also object to your use of *digital* vs. *analog*, as many digital devices these days (PCs, phones, digital watches/clocks) are perfectly capable of displaying an analog clock face. So once again, if you don't specifically mention digital *devices*, but simply leave it at "I can't read analog", you sidestep that issue as well.

Comment: 1. A clock is a timepiece that shows the time of the day.

Comment: 2. Today, "timepiece" is used (in the few cases) for a small clock such as a table clock, a pocket watch or such, the kind specifically called a "not a clock" in the question.

Comment: More abstract: [measuring device for (temporal) extent](http://www.getty.edu/vow/AATFullDisplay?find=clock&logic=AND&note=&english=N&prev_page=1&subjectid=300041575)

Comment: @Kris Yeah, this answer got upvoted but is wrong for modern English. A grandfather clock is a 'timepiece' only in the sense that they're usually antiques from another time. No one would ever call it their timepiece.

Answer (score 6):

> I can't read (the hands on) clocks.

It stands to reason that the speaker is referring to any time mechanism which uses the traditional [**12-hour dial**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock).

> During the 15th and 16th centuries, the 12-hour analog dial and time
>   system gradually became established as standard throughout Northern
>   Europe for general public use. The 24-hour analog dial was reserved
>   for more specialized applications, such as astronomical clocks and
>   chronometers, and timetables, especially for railway and airline
>   travel.

Wikipedia suggests that the term ***clock face*** is used for both clocks and watches

> A [clock face](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_face) or dial is the part of an analog clock (or watch) that
>   displays the time through the use of a fixed-numbered dial or dials
>   and moving hands. In its most basic form, recognized throughout the
>   world, the periphery of the dial is numbered 1 through 12 indicating
>   the hours in a 12-hour cycle, and a **short hour hand** makes two
>   revolutions in a day. A **longer minute hand** makes one revolution every
>   hour.

I suppose you could say: "I can't read twelve-hour dials" and be understood, but it's not very idiomatic.

EDIT

The expression ***read a clock*** is understood to mean watches and all mechanical clocks.

On a British reality show called "I'm A Celebrity... Get Me Out of Here!" one contestant confesed to not being able to tell the time.

> ... he earned himself some airtime by admitting that he **didn’t know
>   how to read a clock-face**. That didn’t matter, he insisted, because **his
>   watch** — reportedly worth £70,000 — was strictly for show, and anyway
>   it didn’t have any numbers on its dial.  ‘It’s fashion,’ he says,
>   adding that it’s ‘much easier to look at your phone’.

Source [Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-2509704/Im-A-Celebrity-2013-The-TV-star-tell-time-70-000-watch-great-career-move.html)

> Ok, earlier today I was at a restaurant and some kids (maybe
>   highschool) asked what time it was so I pointed to a clock on the wall
>   and they stood there sort of silent. Then I heard one say to their
>   friends, "I'm really bad at telling time can you guys read it?"
>
> Long story short none of them could read it but after a few minutes
>   they figured it out. Also now that I think about it, I have overheard
>   some teenagers talking about how **they can't read a clock**.

Source: [www.neowin.net](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/630236-some-people-cant-tell-time/)

> **Reading a Clock**
>   Reading a clock takes practice, but after you learn how, it’s very easy to do! First, you’re going to locate the
>   hour hand. The hour hand is the shorter of the two clock hands.

Source: [wikiHow to Read a Clock](http://www.wikihow.com/Read-a-Clock)

Comment: Why has this answer been downvoted? I don't see it...

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano because my answer is not based on a single word that refers to both watches and clocks. But I can tell you one thing, for free, if you say to anyone *"I can't read timepieces"* people will think you are very odd. You might get away with "I can't read analog" if the context is crystal clear.

Answer (score 4):

The idiomatic way to say this (albeit not a hypernym) is

> I cannot tell the time

"To tell the time" is the idiomatic (phrasal?) verb used for the activity of determining the time from an analog dial; it would not imply a digital display, nor does it suggest a watch face or a clock face. "Learning to tell the time" is a common phrase among parents of pre-school children.

Incidentally, the use of 'analog' here is unnecessary; the context of 'clock' in the phrase 'reading the time from a clock' implies that the clock is analog, and the word is unusual in non-technical contexts. It is also incongruous; generally those who cannot tell the time do not know the word 'analog'.

It appears the American English version of "to tell the time" is "to tell time".

Answer (score 4):

Less casual than "timepiece" is *chronometer*.

Comment: On the other hand, in some contexts chronometer might refer to a [certified (mechanical) chronometer watch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronometer_watch).

Comment: Or those [timepieces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marine_chronometer) they used to carry on ships to aid in navigation.

Answer (score 1):

"Timepiece" is the correct hypernym, but in this context you could also say

> I can't read analog *clock faces*.

The [clock face](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_face) is the part of the device that you read, and it's called a "clock face" even if it's part of a watch rather than a clock.  (It's also called a "dial", but saying you can't read analog dials would imply that you can't read analog voltmeters, barometers etc. either, so "clock face" is better in this context.)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old and this will be buried at the bottom but the ticked and much-upvoted response of *timepiece* matches the dictionary definitions—although Wiktionary's can be at least be quickly corrected—but is completely incorrect. Not only would native speakers never say 'I cannot read a timepiece' (OP's original question) but in practice 
**timepiece is *not* the hypernym of clocks and watches**.
Informal use would restrict timepiece to only smaller chronometers, and preeningly formal use would restrict it to only nonsounding chronometers or to the time display on larger clocks. There is no actual sense of timepiece in modern English where it would ever be applied to an entire grandfather clock.

> Yesterday I said: "I can't read analog clocks", but my interlocutor corrected me saying that what I was pointing at was a watch and not a clock.

Your interlocutor either has poor English or was being pedantic. All watches are clocks in actual English. **[Clock](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/clock) *is* the hypernym of large clocks ("clocks") and small clocks ("watches").** It sometimes only means mechanical timepieces but there are readily understandable senses in which it means any timekeeping device, including sundials and waterclocks (clepsydras). There are some other actual hypernyms (chronometer, horologium, &c.) but they're all pretty uncommon and unhelpful in general use.

"I can't read analog clocks" is exactly what you should've said and you were misled that it was wrong or that timepiece would've been better, in that context or in most others.